# Node: Control flow, Can't save FB friends to db with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

first off thank you for your help. I am trying to make a call to the facebook api to gather all of my users friends.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: config.fb.id,
  clientSecret: config.fb.secret,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({
      "facebook.id" : profile.id
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      //No user was found... so create a new user with values from Facebook (all the profile. stuff)
      if (!user) {
```

this is the call back I am made to return the data

```
        function viewback(err, data, user) {
          if(err) {
            console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
          } else {
            return data;
          }
        }
```

below is where I am making the call for friends, the data variable is not getting set before the call to create the user is being completed and it is not saving the data.

```
        var fbapi = require('facebook-api');
        var client = fbapi.user(accessToken); // do not set an access token
        process.nextTick(function(){
          var data = client.me.friends(viewback);
        });

        user = new User({
          name: profile.displayName,
          username: profile.username,
          profileUrl: profile.profileUrl,
          provider: 'facebook',
          token: accessToken,
          //now in the future searching on User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id } will match because of this next line
          facebook: profile._json
          fb_friends: data
        });
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          console.log('making a new user')
          return done(err, user);
        });
      } else {
        //found user. Return
        console.log('found the user')
        return done(err, user);
      }
    });
}));
```

I don't receive any errors and the user saves in the DB, but without the friend data. Any help would be great. Even better would be something I could read to pick up on this concept.

Comment: process.nextTick is going to fire after the current set of code is executed. Why not keep it simple and move the user saving code into a callback for client.me.friends?

Comment: Chris, That worked out perfectly, but do you have any suggestions for avoiding what they call "callback hell"?

Comment: YES!!! https://github.com/caolan/async will become your new best friend. Once you use it a couple times it becomes second nature. Start with async.series, you can easily refactor your code to use that rather than nested callbacks.

Comment: I will put in a plug for Q promises as well, which while not as widely used as async is the #11 most depended on npm lib, so it's not exactly obscure. This may be a style preference, but I do prefer it. https://github.com/kriskowal/q